# Where is Internet Explorer 10 history stored?

Tags: internet, windows-explorer, internet-explorer, history

I'm using Windows7 64 and Internet Explorer 10.

I find a strange thing about my IE history: I can search history for certain pages and they show, but they are not in any of those "View by Date", "View by site"..etc, because the visiting time of those pages are ealier than that of the oldest history in my browser, probably due to me recently resetting IE, and deleted most of the history. But why they are searchable?

I checked

> ..AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temperory Internet files

and

> ..\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\history

But those pages are definately not there. But where else can they be?

I right clicked the search result of those pages to see property, and it says "type: Internet shortcut"?

I really want to trace down all the browsing history around that date, I thought they were gone, but they are searchable, can anyone help me figure this out? Where is all Internet Explorer history stored?

Comment: They are aearchable because they were cached the history was wiped when you reset ie

Comment: I tried to search cache folders but couldn't find them. If I set internet explorer to offline mode and cut the network, these searchable urls can't really display webpages offline, so I guess they are not cached. I'm still wondering where are these internet shortcut located? so misterious.Really want to retrieve my entire browsing history following these searchable results.